# Create an A domain only for a certain path

Tags: dns, a-records

I have a domain from GoDaddy and it is using the DNS of digitalocean. In addition I have a website at weebly.

Now the website at weebly should have the domain www.example.com/ while my server at digitalocean should have every path apart from the root, so for example www.example.com/test . Is this possible with an A record?

Answer (score 0):

No. DNS records are per server, they don't have anything to do with subdirectories.

I don't know why exactly you would want do do this, but if i were you, i'd make the DNS record point to digitalocean, and make the index page of the digitalocean server a frameset that consists of one frame that has the weebly page as content.

Or, on the digitalocean server, activate the mod_proxy and mod_rewrite apache modules, and create a rule similar to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$  http://weebly.example.com/ [P]
```

which makes the digitalocean server fetch the weebly start page and display it as its own, just for the start page.